# Javascript code alternative

Tags: javascript, html

i'm doing a project for university and i must follow certain specs given by my teacher. In particular i cannot use innerHTML or InnertText. How can i replace that code without using innerHTML/innerText?

HTML:

```
<div class = "boardtitle">

    <text>LAST SCORE: </text>

    <div id="lastscore"></div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function lastScore(num){
     document.getElementById('lastscore').innerText = num;
}
```

Assuming a call like `lastScore(3);` i just want to see the number 3 next to `LAST SCORE:` in the HTML page, how can i replace it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not using `.innerHTML` O.o

Comment: If the teacher also prohibited using `innerText()`, what they *may* have meant was for you to programmatically remove and create the elements using `document.createElement()` rather than writing them as a HTML or text string. See examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement Not sure though. This may need more context. Maybe you need to ask your teacher.

Comment: Look at the [Document#createTextNode documentation example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)

Comment: Yes i can't use innerHTML as innerText

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you are not using `innerHTML` already, but I just assume you cannot use `innerText`. Here you go:

```
function lastScore(num){
    var el = document.getElementById('lastscore');
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(num));
}
```

The plain text inside the HTML elements is also a `DomNode`, a special kind of it, a `TextNode`, which only contains text and no markup. The `document` object also has a method for creating such nodes, the `document.createTextNode('some string')`, which creates a `TextNode` just like any other regular type of Nodes. So you create a TextNode with your custom content and just append it to your element.

UPDATE: I did not get your question entirely correctly: if you want to place the number adjacent to the **LAST SCORE:** text, use the same JS code, but place the id on the `<text>` element which contains **LAST SCORE:**, and remove the `<div>`

Comment: And what if `lastScore()` is called more than once?

Comment: Yeah, I understand this behavior  is completely counterintuitive, but the question was to replace the code with an equivalent code without using `innerText` or `innerHTML`, so this is still a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to append the number after `<text>` element value, your can add the `lastscore` id to your `<text id="lastscore">LAST SCORE: </text>` element, no need to use the extra **div** element `<div id="lastscore"></div>`

```js
function lastScore(num){
     document.getElementById('lastscore').textContent += num;
}

lastScore(3);
```

```html
<div class = "boardtitle">

    <text id="lastscore">LAST SCORE: </text>

</div>
```

**As per comment** : then use `textContent` and see what is the difference of it than innerHTML or innerText here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: There is always someone at SO who likes to down vote without giving the reason :

Comment: Not my downvote, but I assume "i cannot use innerHTML or InnertText" has something to do with it

Comment: @JJJ see me edit, then without innerHTML or innerText, instead use `textContent`

Answer (score -2):

Use `span` instead of `div`. You should get the desired result.

```
<div class = "boardtitle">

    <text>LAST SCORE: </text>

    <span id="lastscore"></span>

</div>

function lastScore(num){
    document.getElementById('lastscore').innerText = num;
}
```

You'll get the number next to `LAST SCORE:` when you call `lastScore(3);`

Comment: with span or div, it works on chrome but it doesn't on firefox, can you tell me why?

Comment: it should work, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

Comment: check this - https://jsfiddle.net/daghachirag/0hr8rwxq/5/

Comment: What difference does the type of content element make? Answer makes no sense